# Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `tcbcol@back'

Tags: color, lyx, tcolorbox

I am work on lyx and i got problem when i generated pdf?!

The error mg:

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `tcbcol@back'.
```

The code of local layout:

```
Style Stop
Category              MainText
Margin                Static
LatexType             Environment
LatexName             stopp
NextNoIndent          1
LeftMargin            MMM
RightMargin           MMM
ParIndent             MM
ParSkip               0
ItemSep               0
TopSep                0.5
BottomSep             0.5
ParSep                0
Align                 Block
AlignPossible         Block, Left, Right, Center
Preamble
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{bclogo}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newtcolorbox{stoppi}[1][]{enhanced,
  before skip=2mm,after skip=3mm,
  boxrule=0.4pt,left=5mm,right=10mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,
  colback=LightSkyBlue!0,
  colframe=blue!20!black,
  sharp corners,rounded corners=southwest,arc is angular,arc=3mm,
  underlay={%
    \path[fill=tcbcol@back!80!black] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south west)--++(0.2,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
    \path[draw=tcbcol@frame,shorten <=-0.05mm,shorten >=-0.05mm] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south west)--++(0.2,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
    \path[fill=MidnightBlue!10,draw=none] (interior.south east) rectangle node[white]{\Huge\bfseries\bcstop} ([xshift=-10mm]interior.north east);
    },
  drop fuzzy shadow,#1}
\newenvironment{stopp}
{\begin{stoppi}}
{\end{stoppi}}
EndPreamble
End
```

Please what's the problem in this code, Regards

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The problem is that you didn't use the `svgnames` option for `xcolor`. However since `tcolorbox` loads `pgf`, which already loads `xcolor`, pass the option through `\documentclass` to avoid an ‘ option clash’ – and it's needless to load xcolor yourself.

Comment: `tcbcol@back` or `tcbcol@frame` are the recently deprecated color names. New names are `tcbcolback` and `tcbcolframe`. See section `9.5 Color Names` is [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) documentation.

Comment: I wanted to close my question as a duplicate of this, but the system won't let me so I've had to go for reverse chronological ordering.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but found the solution here
https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/68

Simply change `tcbcol@back` to `tcbcolback`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Thanks for your answer. As the OP provided a MWE it would be nice to show the complete and working MWE.